# Git prepare-commit-msg

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks

My Code:

```sh
COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
SHA1=$3

git diff --cached --name-status > ./.git/test.txt
git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT | sed -n 's/^\(.*>\).*$/Signed-off-by: \1/p'>> .git/test.txt

SOB=$(cat .git/test.txt)
 git interpret-trailers --in-place --trailer "$SOB" "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
```

I try to get the output of `git diff --cached --name-status` at the end of the git commit message and that works but the weird part is that if I use `git commit` and then close the file (COMMIT_EDITMSG) the commit will be committed but if I make a comment out `git diff --cached --name-status > ./.git/test.txt` then the commit can be aborted through just not editing the file and that is what I try to fix but it seems to I can't any suggestions?

example output is:

```
M   README.md
Signed-off-by: NAME \<E-Mail\>
```